# Is one mutable reference in Rust really enforced?

Tags: rust, reference, mutable

I just started on Rust couple days ago and work through concept of ownership now.

So ok - you can't have more than one mutable reference - I dig that - so this fails:

```
let mut s4= String::from("ZOOT");
let s5 = &mut s4;
let s6 = &mut s4; //error here - second mutable borrow occurs here
s5.push_str(" suit"); //added this line to force error on s6
```

but why is this allowed???

```
let mut s4= String::from("ZOOT");
let s5 = &mut s4;
s5.push_str(" suit");
let s6 = &mut s4; //but WHY NOT here?
```

and yes `println!("s6 = {} ", s6);` prints `ZOOT suit`.

PS. I do understand that after the line `let s6 = &mut s4;` the `s5` is no longer accessible - if you try then suddenly compiler wakes up and throws error on `s6` declaration. But should it throw fit - on the second reference to `s4` with or without `s5` being used to modify content of `s4`?

Comment: *you can't have more than one mutable reference - I dig that - so this fails:* [no it doesn't](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dba9f912897b2aa4d7503405978d9360).

Comment: Actually you are right - it fails only if I try to use reference to `s5`. Lemme upgrade the question.

Comment: Very complete and interesting answer to my borderline trivial observation. Thank you very much - great read!